# Esper - polymorphism between eventtypes

Tags: java, esper, epl

I am trying to use Esper.

My question is about polymorphism between events.

Example (pseudocode):

I use two classes GPSEvent and PositionEvent as eventtypes. They may look like:

```
class GPSEvent{
    double longitude
    double latitude
}
```

and

```
class PositionEvent extends GPSEvent{
    Date timeOfOccurence
}
```

If I use the Rule:

```
select * from GPSEvent.win:length_batch(5)
```

and following Events would be sent into the engine: GPSEvent **g1**, GPSEvent **g2**, GPSEvent **g3**, GPSEvent **g4**, PositionEvent **p1**

the rule would **trigger**.

My question is now how to prevent the triggering if **subtype** events are sent

or

how to trigger only if the eventtype is the **supertype** without any subtypes?

Are there any best practices without adding complexity to the rules oder use "overhead" inside of the eventtype classes?

---

Additional information:

I would like to route a PositionEvent into the engine out of a subscriber after detecting 5 GPSEvents

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways. You can add a flag to the class (no overhead as its a const, for example "getType() {return "P"}", this provides a property "type").
You can make a EPL UDF for custom checking. You can use "instanceof/typeof".